# Laptop reboots when spacebar is tapped

Tags: windows-8

When I continuously tap spacebar on my laptop keyboard the laptop restarts. Event log shows this error:

```
a multi touch device reported inconsistent information event id 264
```

I had updated the all the drivers including BIOS. Hardware diagnostics show  all tests passing. Could this be an OS issue?

Comment: Make a Linux bootable flash drive and test it and see if it still does it, if it does it's a hardware issue, if it doesn't then it's a software issue and you should probably just wipe and reload Windows.... You are not giving us any information to go on other than that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a Linux convert and (ubuntu at least) could care less about my touch screen. Point is, I wouldn't use Linux to troubleshoot a touchscreen issue.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Wait... what does this have to do with a touch screen? The original question was about a keyboard, which is generally safe to assume is a physical keyboard on a laptop. There was no mention of a virtual or soft keyboard in the question.

Comment: @acejavelin.. "a multi touch device" is a touchscreen..